# How can I ignore the constructor attributes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class with constructor, as example:

```
class Student():
    def __init__(self):
        self.firstname = ''
        self.lastname = ''
        self.number = -1
```

I use this constructor to compare the input values ​​in the next method:

```
def transferdata(self, firstname, lastname, number):
    if (type(firstname) == type(self.firstname) and
        type(lastname) == type(self.lastname) and
        type(number) == type(self.number) and
        self.__Enterdata(firstname, lastname, number)
    else:
        return print('No data entry can be performed!')

def __Enterdata(self, firstname, lastname, number):
    self.firstname = firstname
    self.lastname = lastname
    self.number = number
```

std = Student()

If I enter another value type in the transferdata, example (
string instead of integer)

std.transferdata('M', 'M', '1')
I get the return ('No data entry can be performed!').

But when I call the "std" in console, I get that as an object ('', '', '-1').

Does anyone know how can I get an object that contains nothing at all?

Many thanks to all :)

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] your question and description is not clear.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please update your post to show how do you use your class. Hint: the class might be ok, but the way you use it might be the reason the object is not updated.

Comment: The syntax in that `if/else` block is wrong: there doesn't appear to be anything to execute if the condition is truthy.

Comment: *"Does anyone know how can I get an object that contains nothing at all?"* - that is an odd question, and I don't see what it has to do with your code.

Comment: Please clarify your description. You are *not* using the constructor in the comparison. You are *not* checking types in your comparison. In fact, even if you would fix the syntax of your ``if`` statement, ``and self.__Enterdata(...)`` returns ``None`` and will always trigger the ``else`` clause.

Answer (score 1):

your condtiton includes `and self.__Enterdata(firstname, lastname, number)`.
I assume you first wanted to make a return in __Enterdate to say if the data is ok.
But you have no return and because of this, the condition is always false.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong design. You should use the initializer to set the effective data, and use some other mechanism to validate the data, ie

```
class Student(object):
    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname, number):
         self.firstname = firstname
         self.lastname = lastname
         self.number = number

    @property
    def firstname(self):
       return self._firstname

    @firstname.setter
    def firstname(self, firstname):
        if not isinstance(firstname, str):
            raise ValueError("firstname must be a string")
        self._firstname = firstname

    @property
    def lastname(self):
       return self._lastname

    @lastname.setter
    def lastname(self, lastname):
        if not isinstance(lastname, str):
            raise ValueError("lastname must be a string")
        self._lastname = lastname

    @property
    def number(self):
        return self._number

    @property.setter
    def number(self, number):
        if not isinstance(number, float):
            raise ValueError("number must be a float")
        self._number = number
```

And now you're ready to use your class in a simple, standard, non-convoluted way:

```
student = Student("foo", "bar", 42.0)

try:
    Student("foo", "bar", "42")
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)
```

The point here is that your data will be "validated" not only on instanciation but also when you try and set the values directly:

```
student = Student("foo", "bar", 42.0)
student.firstname = 666
```

Note that I just used the builtin `property` type here - which makes for some redundant code - but [you can write your own computed attributes types](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) to keep your code DRY.

For more advanced validation scheme, you can also have a look at Django's `forms` lib (much more involved, but it's solid, working and mostly well written code).